# How to force install all dependencies in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, zappa

I am trying to deploy my flask app on AWS Lambda by using Zappa. I carefully followed all the tutorials but I always get deployment error :

```
Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code.
```

I entered `zappa tail` and I figured out that the dependencies are not installed even after I made `pip freeze > requirements.txt` . The problem is, there are a lot of dependencies and it really boring to install each of them manually.

Is there any magic command that will allow me to automatically install all dependencies in the `virtualenv` ?

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt` is this the thing you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just run
`pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: It returns me for each dependency `Requirement already satisfied`. I also tried to replace `pip` by `pipenv` but I get a `✘ Locking Failed! ` error (`There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies:
  werkzeug==1.0.1`)

Comment: I hope you are trying that after activating the new venv?